# progress spinner

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

How do I show a progress spinner during an ajax call? I got the spinner gif from [Link](http://www.ajaxload.info/) and my code to make ajax call is using Dojo:

```
  dojo.xhrPost( { 
      form: formName, 
      sync: true,
      handleAs: "text", 
      load: function(response) {
       //Spinner should be called here.. How?
          //populate content here
           successMessage();
             }  ,
        error: function(error, ioargs){

          //do something with errors
```

Comment: The line "//Spinner should be called here" inside the "load" function indicates that you have a problem with the concept of an async call.  JavaScript is all async.  "load" and "error" are *callback* functions, which are called when the task is already done.  If you want to wrap your async call with a spinner popup/teardown pair, you have to put the popup call **before** you do the async call, and the teardown call in the callback functions.  This is called continuation-style programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have global javascript functions (eg `showAjaxWorking()`, `hideAjaxWorking()` to show/hide a div containing a spinner image, positioned in a standard place, or somehwere specific if that suits..

```
showAjaxWorking();
dojo.xhrPost( { 
      form: formName, 
      sync: true,
      handleAs: "text", 
      load: function(response) {
       hideAjaxWorking();
           successMessage();
             }  ,
        error: function(error, ioargs){

          //do something with errors
           hideAjaxWorking();
```